# Programming CUDA without a graphics card? Are there (good) emulators?

Tags: windows-7, cuda, emulation

Are there any good emulators for CUDA on Windows7 (64 bit) which wouldn't cause any compatibility problems?

I would also like to know the procedure to install the emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

See:
[Ocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/)

The website states:
*Ocelot currently allows CUDA programs to be executed on NVIDIA GPUs, AMD GPUs, and x86-CPUs at full speed without recompilation.*

Keep in mind that CUDA was designed for GPU. Running on a CPU will drop performance significantly.

Answer (score 3):

The emulation mode is not supported by the latest version of cuda toolkit.
What I do for my work is, use the cuda sdk 2.3 and cuda toolkit 2.3 (it is pretty old, but suffices my work)

You can find the cuda toolkit 2.3 here: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Compile the code using the "-deviceemu" flag. 
If you are accustomed to using cuda specific make files, you can compile the code using "make emu=1"

This way the binary can be run on any machine without GPU.
Of-course, the execution efficiency is very low!

Once the code is doing what I want it to do, I deploy it in the lab machine and compile it with CUDA 4.0.

PS: you may sometimes lose out on the features provided by latest CUDA toolkit.

Comment: I installed cuda toolkit 2.3. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @maddie, you can compile the code using nvcc <filename.cu> --deviceemu